# link-to action parameters are not working in ember js

Tags: ember.js

Hi i am very new to ember js. i pass action parameters(id ) on link-to action in template but i did not get the values in my controller.

My  Template code as follows:

index.html:

```
             <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="search">

             {{#each model.results}}

             // here i pass id value along with action

             {{#link-to 'profile' id action="profileinfo"}}

             </script>
```

app.js:

```
          App.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

             id: '',

             actions:{
               profileinfo: function(id){

                // Here i access id value like this
               console.log(id);
               var id = this.get('id');})
```

when i click on the link action goes to Searchcontroller, but i get id value is empty.I follow some solutions in stack overflow but unfortunately i did not get anything. Please provide some solution

Comment: You have given the python tag for this even though it is quite clearly not python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Combine linkTo and action helpers in Ember.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124381/combine-linkto-and-action-helpers-in-ember-js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't get why you're using the `{{#link-to}}` helper for triggering an action on your controller. Maybe you could simply use the `{{action}}` helper ?

If you try doing it that way, would it work ?

```
<button type="button" {{action "profileinfo" id}}>Click me !</button>
```

From there, your `console.log(id);` should get your value.

**EDIT**

Would also work for a `<a>` tag

```
<a href="#" {{action "profileinfo" id}}>Click me !</a>
```

Comment: I can think of a scenario where you would want a `link-to` and also an `action`: say you have a button that you'd like to take the `active` state (which you get if it's a `link-to`) and you'd like the fact that the button was pressed to bubble up to a parent controller so that something can happen in the parent view (which normally wouldn't change if you were just routing to a child route in an outlet).

Comment: I would still prefer to use a proper action in the model, that will then call a `this.transitionToRoute`. I basically think that `{{#link-to}}` must be restricted to basics redirections. If you want to want to handle a more complex logic, you gotta give this to `view` or even `controller`

Comment: @PascalBoutin: I don't think that transitions should be triggered outside of routes, to ensure separation of concerns. The router routes, the controller processes actions ... Besides, as @neverfox mentions, `link-to` offers much more than simple redirection. There is an addon that extends link-to with action processing capabilities (https://github.com/Kuzirashi/ember-link-action), but it is not working for me right now (ember@2.2.0)

Comment: @delavnog Hey my addon should definitely work for you, I have updated it to Ember 2.8 but it's working even for 1.13. Please try again and create issue if something is wrong still. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've created popular addon for doing just that:

```
{{#link-to 'profile' id invokeAction='profileinfo'}}
```

Simply install it:

`ember install`[`ember-link-action`](https://github.com/Kuzirashi/ember-link-action)

Please leave a star if you enjoy it or leave feedback if you feel anything is missing. :) It works with Ember 1.13 and 2.X (tested on Travis CI).