# Click events on Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-bootstrap

I'm discovering EmberJS and started to migrate an existing website to this framework. I was having an issue with a Bootstrap-based dropdown. This issue actually helped me understand Ember's concepts a bit better but I still have some questions.

I used the [ember-bootstrap](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/) module to generate this dropdown (among other things) and here is what the code is supposed to be:

```
{{#bs-dropdown as |dd|}}
  {{#dd.button}}
    Sort by
  {{/dd.button}}

  {{#dd.menu as |ddm|}}
    {{#ddm.item}}{{#ddm.link-to "index"}}Price low to high{{/ddm.link-to}}{{/ddm.item}}
    {{#ddm.item}}{{#ddm.link-to "index"}}Price high to low{{/ddm.link-to}}{{/ddm.item}}
  {{/dd.menu}}
{{/bs-dropdown}}
```

Now, I want some javascript code to be executed when the user clicks on one of the items. After checking [the module's documentation](https://www.ember-bootstrap.com/api/classes/Components.DropdownMenuItem.html),  I found where the *menu item* component was defined and edited its code as follows:

```
export default Component.extend({
  layout,
  classNameBindings: ['containerClass'],

  /* ... */

  actions: {
    // My addition
    sortByPrice(param){
      alert("sorting");
    },
    // End of the addition

    toggleDropdown() {
      if (this.get('isOpen')) {
        this.send('closeDropdown');
      } else {
        this.send('openDropdown');
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Then I updated the hbs file as follows:

```
{{#dd.menu as |ddm|}}
   {{#ddm.item action "sortByPrice" low_to_high}}

    {{#ddm.link-to "index"  action "sortByPrice" low_to_high}}
      Prix croissant
    {{/ddm.link-to}}

  {{/ddm.item}}
{{/dd.menu}}
```

This didn't work, and that's why you I added the `*action*` to the `link-to` element as well and declared similarly the action on its component file.

```
import LinkComponent from '@ember/routing/link-component';

export default LinkComponent.extend({
  actions: {
    sortByPrice(param){
        alert("sorting");
      console.log("sorting");
      },
  },
});
```

As you can see, the `*link-to*` component extends the *LinkComponent* one. I eventually understood that it wasn't possible for this element to handle click events natively, as explained in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124381/combine-linkto-and-action-helpers-in-ember-js).

Out of frustration, I ended up with a less elegant approach that still does the trick:

```
{{#bs-dropdown id="sort" as |dd|}}
  {{#dd.button}}
    Sort by
  {{/dd.button}}

  {{#dd.menu as |ddm|}}
    {{#ddm.item action "sortByPrice" low_to_high}}
      <a
        class="dropdown-item"
        onclick="sortByPrice('low_to_high'); return false;"
        href="#"
      >
        Price low to high
      </a>
    {{/ddm.item}}
  {{/dd.menu}}
{{/bs-dropdown}}
```

Now here are my questions:

1. Why is it that defining actions on both the Component file and the hbs one didn't change the result?
2. Why doesn't the LinkComponent handle click events natively? I get that a link is supposed to redirect users to a new page (which is still arguable), but the DOM event is still fired, so does Ember deliberately ignore it and choose not to let developers handle it? I want to know the logic behind this.
3. Is there a better approach than my solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cheers for studying EmberJS and posting a beautiful, explicit question!

## Your mistakes

1. Never modify the code inside `node_modules/` and `bower_components/` folders. If you really need to monkey-patch something, you can do it in an initializer. But your use case does not require monkey patching.
2. You attempted to define an action in the menu item component, but you apply it in a parent template. That action has to be defined in that parent's template component/controller.
3. This invocation is incorrect:

   ```
   {{#ddm.link-to "index"  action "sortByPrice" low_to_high}}
   ```

   Here are the problems:

   1. The `ddm.link-to` component is supposed to create a link to another route. It does not seem to support passing an action into it.
   2. You're just passing a bunch of positional params to the component. If `ddm.link-to` did support accepting an action, the correct invocation would look like this:

      ```
      {{#ddm.link-to "index" argName=(action "sortByPrice" low_to_high)}}
      ```

      In this case, `"index"` is a position param and `argName` is a named param.
   3. `low_to_high` without quotes is a reference to a property defined on the current scope. You probably meant a string instead: `"low_to_high"`.
4. Never use JS code in template directly. This you should never do in Ember:

   ```
   <a onclick="sortByPrice('low_to_high'); return false;">
   ```

   Instead, pass an action (defined in the local scope: in a component or controller):

   ```
   <a onclick={{action 'sortByPrice' 'low_to_high'}}>
   ```

   The `onclick` property name is optional. An action defined without a property implies `onclick` (you only need to provide the property name if you need to attach the action to a different event):

   ```
   <a {{action 'sortByPrice' 'low_to_high'}}>
   ```

   For the link to be styled properly in a browser, a `href` attribute is required. But you don't have to pass a value `'#'` to it. The hash symbol was required in old-school apps to prevent the link from overwriting the URL. Ember overrides URL overwriting for you, so you can simply pass an empty `href`.

   Here's the final correct usage:

   ```
   <a href {{action 'sortByPrice' 'low_to_high'}}>
   ```

---

## Answers to your questions

> 1. Why is it that defining actions on both the Component file and the hbs one didn't change the result?

Because you defined them in different scopes.

If you define an action in `app/components/foo-bar.js`, the action must be applied in `app/templates/components/foo-bar.hbs`.

If you define an action in `app/controllers/index.js`, the action must be applied in `app/templates/index.hbs`.

> 2. Why doesn't the `LinkComponent` handle click events natively? I get that a link is supposed to redirect users to a new page (which is still arguable), but the DOM event is still fired, so does Ember deliberately ignore it and choose not to let developers handle it? I want to know the logic behind this.

In a PWA, you do not do actual page redirects. Such a redirect would reload the whole app.

Instead, the `LinkComponent` overrides the click and tell the Ember's routing system to perform a transition. Routes must be set up properly and the route passed to the `LinkComponent` must exist.

It seems that your goal is not to perform a transition but to change a variable, so the `LinkComponent` is not applicable here. That's unless you wire the sort order property to an URL query param, in which case you can change the sort order by making a transition to a different query param.

> 3. Is there a better approach than my solution?

See below for the simplest approach that uses `ember-bootstrap`'s dropdown.

---

## A working example

Controller:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  isSortAccending: true,

  actions: {
    changeSortDirection (isSortAccending) {
      this.set('isSortAccending', isSortAccending);
    }
  }
});
```

Template:

```
<p>
  Current sort order:
  {{if isSortAccending "ascending" "descending"}}
</p>

{{#bs-dropdown as |dd|}}
  {{#dd.button}}
    Sort by
  {{/dd.button}}

  {{#dd.menu as |ddm|}}
    {{#ddm.item}}
      <a href {{action "changeSortDirection" true}}>
        Price high to low
      </a>
    {{/ddm.item}}

    {{#ddm.item}}
      <a href {{action "changeSortDirection" false}}>
        Price high to low
      </a>
    {{/ddm.item}}
  {{/dd.menu}}
{{/bs-dropdown}}
```

Here's a [working demo](https://ember-twiddle.com/d4b55813a279b862eb5e98820a752f21?numColumns=2&openFiles=controllers.application.js%2Ctemplates.application.hbs).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! I got my answers but I have a few comments. First, you mentioned an "initializer" but I can't figure out what it is. Then can you elaborate on the syntax you use with the "argName"? Finally, can you point me in the right direction for interacting with the URL? Thanks.

Comment: Those are all separate & huge topics, I can't explain all Ember basics in one answer.

Comment: "you mentioned an initializer but I can't figure out what it is" -- Seriously? Have you even tried googling? The answer is the first result when googling fo "ember initializer". https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/initializers/

Comment: "can you elaborate on the syntax you use with the argName" -- https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/passing-properties-to-a-component/

Comment: "can you point me in the right direction for interacting with the URL?" -- https://guides.emberjs.com/release/routing/query-params/

Comment: @user1319182, don't forget to accept the answer. ^_^

Comment: Thank you for the replies :)

Comment: *The `onclick` property name is optional.* <-- this is wrong! See [here why!](https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/deep-dive-on-ember-events-cf684fd3b808) One is a *closure action* one a *classic action* while they behave similar in *some* cases it makes a *huge* difference in other cases. I would recommend to *never use classic actions* for new code!

Comment: @Lux It makes no difference in this particular case (and in 99.9% cases, IMO -- the only time i needed `onclick` was to get access to the event object). And regarding the article, don't you think this level of detail is to much for a user who doesn't even understand the syntax and attempts `{{#ddm.item action "sortByPrice" low_to_high}}`?