# ember-intl for translating html

Tags: ember.js, ember-intl

I'm using [ember-intl](https://ember-intl.github.io/ember-intl/versions/master/docs/quickstart) and would like to translate html (href with link):

`en-us.json`:

```
{
   "sign-up": "Didn't get it? check your spam folder, or try to '<a {myLink}>'send a new passcode'</a>'",
}
```

My controller has an action that is called: signUp:

```
actions: {
    signUp: function() {
      console.log('success');
    },
}
```

In my hbs file, I tried:

```
{{{t 'sign-up' myLink=(action 'signUp')}}}
```

The text was set, and the link looks as a link, but when I click on this link, the log is not written.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can pass a translation string to ember-intl which would be interpreted as a glimmer template. Or to say it differently: You can not use modifiers within a translation string. You must separate the strings and render the `<a>` element including the modifier in the template directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check this thread in stackoverflow:

[Combine linkTo and action helpers in Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124381/combine-linkto-and-action-helpers-in-ember-js)

probably after installing the library

```
ember-link-action
```

you can do something like

```
{{#link-to 'other-route' invokeAction=(action 'signUp')}}
  {{t 'sign-up'}}
{{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Thank you!
As I understand, the sign-up text will be clickable and not only: "send a new passcode".
(I know I can separate my string in order to make this text clickable)